# Renaming hundreds of non-empty directories

Tags: rename

OS is Centos 7

I've looked for a couple days now and feel like I should have found something for this by now.

I have hundreds and hundreds of directories like the following:

```
/tmp/user1/app/webapp/foo/bar.txt
/tmp/user2/app/webapp/etc/bar1.txt
/tmp/user3/app/webapp/whatever/bar2.txt
/tmp/user4/app/webapp/sure/bar3.txt
```

And I need to change 'webapp' to 'new_webapp'

Both `/tmp/` and `/app/` are constant but the users and the content under the directory to be renamed is unknown and varied. Every existing directory structure is not empty.

I have not found a way to succinctly do this without manually slogging through each directory with a laborious shuffling of files in and out of directories and I'm hoping someone might know of a more efficient way.

Comment: Given that you don't care about the content under the `webapp` directory, is the directory *depth* always the same? So it's /tmp/(something)/app/webapp, or could it be /tmp/(something)/(something else)/app/(something yet again)/webapp?  Also, do you care about the content underneath? Do they contain links that include `webapp` that might need to be changed?

Comment: I do care what's under it; it needs to be preserved. It's just that there is an unknown depth and content under it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just rename them?

With util-linux rename:

```
rename -v webapp new_webapp /tmp/user*/app/webapp
```

With find (variable depth):

```
find /tmp -depth -type d -name "webapp" -execdir mv webapp new_webapp \;
```

A for loop with mv:

```
for path in /tmp/user*/app/
do
    mv -v "$path"/webapp "$path"/new_webapp
done
```

None of these cover any special cases, like what happens if new_webapp already exists (error checking / conflict resolution), webapp is actually a mountpoint, or a symlink instead of actual directory, or other things refering to this directory structure you're re-designing.

So it can be quite a lot more complicated than a simple rename, it depends.

But if you were asking about these it was not clear from your question.

Comment: Worth mentioning that, if speed is important, the "util-linux" (not "coreutils", by the way) rename is much faster, since it does not fork once per file.

Comment: @sitaram my mistake, thanks

Comment: That did it! I was unfamiliar with the `rename` command haha.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
find /tmp -depth -type d -name webapp -exec sh -c 'mv "${0}" "${0%/webapp}/new_webapp"' {} \;
```

Comment: Note that this would change the name of _any_ directory called `webapp`, regardless where under `/tmp` it is located.